# How do I make a class a sub-group of another class?

Tags: python, django, class, e-commerce

```
from django.db import models  

class products(models.Model): #Table name, has to wrap models.Model to get the functionality of Django.  

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True) #Like a VARCHAR field  
    description = models.TextField() #Like a TEXT field  
    price = models.IntegerField()


    def __unicode__(self): #Tell it to return as a unicode string (The name of the to-do item) rather than just Object.  
        return self.name  


class categories(models.Model):
```

I'm a python newbie and I'm trying to create an e-commerce store. As you can see above, I've created the products class, but in the Categories class, I need to include all the products I create come under a certain category. I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: go through django documentation, and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009010/how-to-display-an-attribute-of-a-foreign-key-in-django-admin-page which would give you ideas

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want a ForeignKey from Product to Category.

Comment: The same way as in the tutorial, where there is a ForeignKey from Choice to Poll. If you haven't done the tutorial, go and do it before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Many to Many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

I think a Product can belong to Many categories so it should have a ManyToMany relationship to the Category model.