# ForeignKey fields in add/change forms - Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Say I have these models as a simple example:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    app = models.ForeignKey(App)

class App(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    app_config = models.ForeignKey(AppConfig)

class AppConfig(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    is_valid = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I want to create an Admin page with add/change forms for `Event` that will allow me to select an `App` and create `AppConfig` with all its fields.

Basically, to have a form with a dropdown to choose an `App` and below it a form to fill in the `AppConfig` fields. Or even just a "+" sign or a link that will popup a form to create an `AppConfig`.

I saw many examples of how to add this to the `list_display` (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009010/how-to-display-an-attribute-of-a-foreign-key-in-django-admin-page)) but couldn't manage to do the same with `fields` or `fieldsets` in order to have it in the add/change form as well.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks!

**Note:** I know that this might be easily solved if I also had `AppConfig` as a foreign key in `Event` but this doesn't really make sense.

**Edit:** My Django and Python versions:
Python: 2.7.x
Django: 1.7.4

**Edit2:** I have found this nice open-source code [django_reverse_admin](https://github.com/daniyalzade/django_reverse_admin) which might be helpful, but first, this specific package support only Django 2.0+. I tried to use the original code which does seem to support previous Django versions but didn't manage to apply it to my specific case.
If anyone have an idea or can show me how to use this in my specific case it will be great. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the admin inlines?

Comment: Hey @Walucas - Admin Inlines are the other way around. They are used with the opposite direction. I actually found [django_reverse_admin](https://github.com/daniyalzade/django_reverse_admin) recently but couldn't manage to make it work with my case. If anyone can show a way to use this to solve my specific case it will be great! Thanks!

Comment: Now it is not clear what you want then.... as far as I understood, you want to manage three(or two) models in one admin page, is that it?

Comment: @Walucas I want to have an `Event` admin page where after choosing an `App` for that event, to be able to edit it's `AppConfig` fields, all this in the same admin add/change form. Thanks!

Comment: got it! you want a Nested Inline like: https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-… or https://github.com/BertrandBordage/django-super-inlines take a look and let me know

Comment: @Walucas - I don't think so. You're right it's some kind of "nested reverse inline" but it's still the **reverse** direction. You are right that if I use inlines I would be able to edit `App` and `Event` from the `AppConfig` page. But I want the opposite, I want to edit `AppConfig`/`App` from the `Event` page. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline)

Answer (score 3):

This package allows you to quickly filter or group "chained" models by adding a custom foreign key or many to many field to your models. This will use an AJAX query to load only the applicable chained objects.

https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

I think, the solution is already talked here
[How to filter a dropdownlist in Django's admin when a selection is made on another dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853595/how-to-filter-a-dropdownlist-in-djangos-admin-when-a-selection-is-made-on-anoth)

Comment: Hey @aldyahsn, I am not sure how this helps me in my case. I think that maybe if I also had `Third` as a foreign key in `First` then I could use that, but it's not my case.  If you still think it can be solved by using this package, can you please give an example? Thanks!